# Compiled code does not load image using qrc in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe

Ive created a program using pyqt4 as GUI Ive used resource file or .qrc to load background image.
My problem is when i compiled it using py2exe, the background image is not loaded.

here is the sample code.

GUI MODULE:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(563, 319)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-image: url(:/test/mr_bean_kid.jpg);"))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 563, 18))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

import ss_rc
```

MAIN MODULE:

```
from sample import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class test(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = test()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i will not include the qrc because its to long.
thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem can be found at the bottom of this page.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt

When trying this solution, make sure you are not bundling all files into a single executable, that won't work...

Answer (score 1):

Is it a Python QRC?

I have a Makefile for my application, which dynamically re-generates the code from the `.ui` files and the `.qrc` file:

**Makefile**:

```
all:
    rm -fv *.pyc
    pyuic4 -i 2 -o gui.py gui.ui
    pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
    python2 main.py
```

In Qt Designer, you specify the resource file. For me, it was `resources.rc`. But Python changes that `.` to an underscore, so you have to create a `resources_rc` file with the `.py` extension.

Comment: thx for the reply Blender. yes its python QRC. It works fine when Ive run it in the source code. It loads the image, but when i compiled it to .exe using py2exe and run it, the image does not appear

Comment: Ahh, that's better. I've always had problems with `py2exe`. Always. Have you tried `cx_freeze`? I build PyQt4 applications myself, and it always packages them nicely.

Comment: I'm trying cx_freeze now and working on it, but still the same problem occurs. No image after being compiled. Ive created a setup.py setup(
        name = "hello",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "the typical 'Hello, world!' script",
        executables = [Executable("main.py")]) just like in the docs example and run it in the command prompt as setup.py build

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today. The problem is simply that py2exe does not recognize "jpg" format image. Your background image has to be a "png" file. You can simply change that by modifying the format of yout image with paint for instance and then add this image to your "resourcefilename.qrc". Then you recompile it. Do not forget to change the link in your python code from :

```
QtGui.QDialog.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QDialog{background-image: url(:/image/**'imagename'.jpg**);}"))
```

to

```
QtGui.QDialog.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QDialog{background-image: url(:/image/**'imagename'.png**);}"))
```

Then, you just have to recompile your code with py2exe and you should now have your background.